# Django w/ MySQL non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv, transactions

Keep getting this warning using a MySQL database:

`Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back`

I'm not sure what it means or if it is even causing a problem but I was hoping someone would be able to fill me in on what this means.

I am taking a CSV file, reading it line-by-line and creating Django objects using `get_or_create`. After I get the message, when I try to recreate it, I get further into the CSV file before the warning occurs.

I tried reading about this error online but I really don't understand what it means. It would be ideal to figure out whats causing this but if I can't I am wondering if I can suppress the warning because maybe it isn't effect my database negatively.

Comment: what db/engines are your tables using?

Comment: MySQL... djando.db.backends.mysql

Comment: Do you know what engine your tables are using? innodb/myisam? Remember that its table by table.

Comment: I have MySQL v5.1.61 so I think its safe to say I have myisam... correct me if thats not a safe assumption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you mix `transactional` and `non-transactional` tables. Changes to non- transactional tables are not effected by a `ROLLBACK` statement.

For some reasons this may have happened to you we can turn to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/nontransactional-tables.html):

> if you were not deliberately mixing transactional and nontransactional tables within the transaction, the most likely cause for this message is that a table you thought was transactional actually is not. This can happen if you try to create a table using a transactional storage engine that is not supported by your mysqld server (or that was disabled with a startup option). If mysqld does not support a storage engine, it instead creates the table as a MyISAM table, which is nontransactional.

This will effect things negatively if you say have an `HTTP` request that kicks of a transaction, you make some changes, and you need to rollback. The transactional tables will rollback but the others will not. If a transactional storage engine is a requirement for your software you should consider taking steps to migrate all the relevant tables to the `InnoDB` engine.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with using `get_or_create()` VS. `try: get()... expect DoesNotExist: ... save()`

Comment: nope it has to do with the table engines inside the DBMS

Comment: I imagine your models have some relationships that join `innoDB` to `myiasm` tables this will cause you to see this error. It comes right outta the `DBMS` its a `MySQL` error not `Django`

Comment: Is there a way to stop this from happening? My script is doing a lot of database transactions using get_or_create(). Is there something I could do mid script to prevent this exception from occuring? Would it be bad practice to wrap the place that it occurs in try, except?

Comment: You can disable django's transaction behavior by setting `AUTOCOMMIT` to `False` in your app's settings. Then you have to manage transactional boundaries yourself. Or you can read what I said you are mixing transactional/non-transactional resources. Inventory your tables and find out which one is the problem and exclude it from the transactional operation.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up finding out why this was occuring. My guess is that setting AUTOCOMMIT to False isn't the cleanest bugfix

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, however I wanted to express concern in that I ran into the same problem using only MyISAM tables. I don't believe one can mix up transactioness on MyISAM tables. Furthermore, this *only* happens when using get_or_create(). Maybe this is a bug with the versions I'm using (Django 1.6.2 and Python 2.7.x), but I wanted to mention it nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened after I imported a table from another Django application. The origin DB had all the table engines set to MyISAM and the destination app had all the engines set as InnoDB. When I imported the existing table the engine was changed from InnoBD to MyISAM to match the source. I resolved this using MySQL on the command line like so:

```
$ mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD
> use MY_DB;
> show table status;
> alter table TABLE_WITH_MYISAM engine=innodb;
> quit;
```

I had imported 5 tables so I had to do the alter command for each table. The show command above will print out the table names and engine settings for all tables in MY_DB.

I hope this helps solve your issue! Cheers!